# What is the max. database size allowed for Azure Managed Instance database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

From the documentation, it is not very clear what is the exact limit for database size (in TBs) using Managed Instnace option in case of Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Its 8 [TeraBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-resource-limits) allowed for sql database managed instance resource

[image]